# SDL Frame Independent Movement Issues

Tags: sdl, sdl2, c

I am using SDL2 with C to program a frame independent movement.

I have a `struct` that defines a position of a sprite (*its top left corner*):

```
struct _point2D {
    /* X coordinate */
    float x;
    
    /* Y coordinate */
    float y;
};
```

Then I have a sprite `struct` itself with multiple fields:

```
struct _sprite {
    /* ... */

    /* Sprite position */
    struct _point2D position;

    /* Sprite velocity */
    struct _vector2D velocity;

    /* ... */
};
```

Vector is defined as following:

```
struct _vector2D {
    /* X velocity */
    float x;

    /* Y velocity */
    float y;
};
```

Here goes the function than handles the movement:

```
int Sprite_move(const Sprite_t sprite, float delta_time) {
    /* =========== VARIABLES ========== */

    /* The operation result */
    int result = -1;

    /* ================================= */



    /* ================================================================== */
    /* ================= Make sure a sprite is not NULL ================= */
    /* ================================================================== */

    if (sprite != NULL) {

        /* Update a sprite X position */
        sprite->position.x += sprite->velocity.x * delta_time;

        /* Update a sprite Y position */
        sprite->position.y += sprite->velocity.y * delta_time;

        /* Success */
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("%s error: %s\n", __func__, "provided sprite is NULL");
    }



    /* ================================= */

    return result;
```

The way I compute `delta_time`:

```
const int VELOCITY = 10; 

while (/* !quit */) {
    
    /* Frame start time */
    start = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

        if ((event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) && (event.key.repeat == 0)) {

            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {

                case SDLK_UP:
                    sprite->velocity.y -= VELOCITY;

                    break ;

                /* ... */
            }
        }
    }
    
    /* Frame end time */
    end = start;

    /* */
    start = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

    /* Compute delta time */
    delta_time = ((start - end) * 1000.0 / (double) SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency());

    /* Move a sprite (Update its position) */
    Sprite_move(sprite, delta_time);

    /* render a sprite */
    Sprite_draw(sprite);

    /* ... */
}
```

The sprite motion seems not to be smooth, more like jumping from one position to another. The first frame it jumps immediately to some point. When I press and hold the button for the first time everything seems OK, in a fraction of a second sprite movement  looks to be smooth, after that period of time it starts to jump again.

**Did I compute something wrong?**

Comment: After the frame finishes ( below `Sprite_draw(sprite);` ) do you have a way to delay the current frame, before the next one begins? Or do frames happen as fast as possible ?